# How to run .sh script (iptables commands) on start up

Tags: lineageos, iptables

I am using LineageOS 18.1

When I was on LOS 16, I used to edit the file `/system/etc/init.d/00banner` and put my iptables commands there, e.g.:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
sh -c 'iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 10195 -d 203.205.255.78/23 -j REJECT'
```

All iptables commands I put in there used to run on phone start up. But in LOS 18.1, the `/system/etc/init.d/` directory was deprecated.

**1.** I created and filled the custom script with the *iptables* commands above:

```
touch /system/etc/custominit.sh
chmod 0755 /system/etc/custominit.sh
```

**2.** Then I edited `/system/etc/init/hw/init.rc` and I added to the end:

```
chmod 0755 /system/etc/custominit
exec /system/etc/custominit
```

**3.** I also tried adding:

```
service custominit /system/bin/custominit.sh
    disabled
    oneshot
```

But none of this worked.

What is it that I doing wrong? I have root access but I do not want to install any additional apps on my phone for this, as it was possible to do on LOS 16.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131710/discussion-on-question-by-light9876-how-to-run-sh-script-iptables-commands-on).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue was solved by following instructions here:

https://ch1p.io/lineageos-run-shell-script-at-boot-as-root/

The main issue turned out to be missing full path of executables, e.g.:

/system/bin/iptables instead of iptables

Comment: ... that doesn't explain why *'echo test >> /data/local/tmp/test.log'* did not work to you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @alecxs echo still did not work, even if I added `/system/bin/echo` it did not work, but `iptables` did. I don't know why..

Comment: echo exist as 1) shell builtin and 2) toybox applet. I think it's bad timing /data is late mounted. anyway never mind, it was just for testing if service is executed - which it obviously does

Answer (score 1):

Once you added your service as "disabled" on init.rc you must call it on boot, add the following lines:

```
on boot
    custominit your_params
```

I hope it solves your problem

Comment: The syntax isn't correct. It should be `start custominit your_params`. But still this might not work due to other reasons.

Comment: No, it did not work..